# matlab/freemat - find time between two points on graph

Tags: matlab

I have the following plot (which is from a WAV file):

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0HeCXXvk2r5SzNpM0dvSjJ1RWM

I'd like to measure the time (the x axis) between the start of the two noisy blocks (between the 2 points where y starts being > 0.02).

I'm using FreeMat so I have no access to Matlab toolboxes.

How can i go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a vector `x` with your x-values and one with your `y` values, use [find](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/help/array_find.html) to find the indices of the corresponding entries in `x` where the condition `y > 0.2` is met.

E.g.:

```
idx_start = find(y > 0.2, 1, 'first')
idx_end = find(y > 0.2, 1, 'last')
```

And then calculate the time of it:

```
deltaT = x(idx_end)-x(idx_start)
```

**EDIT**::
Okay I had a little missunderstanding in my answer. As I haven't got too much background information about your process and how the data may look like in another case, I'm proposing you two ways of doing it:

---

A) You could simply do do something like this:

```
idx_start = find(y > 0.2, 1, 'first')
idx_end = find(y(ceil(length(y)/2)) > 0.2, 1, 'last')
```

Depending on how your data looks like, i.e. if the second peak is always in the second half or not.

---

B) You could first convert every single peak into a logical vector, like this:

```
idx = y > 0.2
```

which might look like something like this:

```
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
```

And then you could search for the occurences of the pattern [0 1] in it which will yield the transition from the low to a high peak in the signal:

```
idx_trans = findstr([0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0],[0 1])
deltaT = x(idx_trans(1)+1)-x(idx_trans(2)+1)
```

which will work when there are two peaks like this and NO noise peaking over 0.2.
I guess findstr also exists in freemat, if not, I found a ported code: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~ramonf/FreeMat/findstr.m

Comment: That gets me the time between the first point > 0.02 and the last. I need the delta between the first point of the first block and the first point of the second block.

Comment: Ok @DepletionMode I posted two methods for now, hopefully you can get the idea behind it and make it work for your case or for a general case if you want to